# Inner div prevents event triggering in parent div

Tags: javascript

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<section id="container">
  <div class="box"><div>inner div</div></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

and the JS code:

```
var section = document.getElementById("container");
    section.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target.className === "box") {
            ...
        }
    });
```

If I click on the text `inner div` the event is not triggered. Why? How can I change that?

Comment: did you check what `event.target.className` return when you click inner div text.it has no class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solution is more general than the other suggested:

```
if (event.target.className === "box" || event.target.parentNode.className === "box")
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I click on the text inner div the event is not triggered. Why?

The event is set to `<div class="box">` element, and `<div>inner div</div>` is on top of it. When you click it can trigger the event only to the top most element and not the elements underneath it.

To make it work set [`pointer-events: none;`](https://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/) on the inner div:

```
<div style="pointer-events:none;">inner div</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqkh39r4/)

Answer (score 0):

As to why it's not triggered; an event is triggered, but event.target.className is not "box" because event.target is not the outer div, but the inner which surrounds the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem occurs because you are clicking on div without `box` class ( it's div which lives in `div.box`). You can see it by clicking on "inner div 2" text:

```js
var section = document.getElementById("container");

section.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.className == "box") {
        alert('box clicked');
    }
});
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <div class="box"><div>inner div 1</div></div>
  <div class="box">inner div 2</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

inner div text Not included class "box" , 
try this code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="container">
          <div class="box"><div class="box">inner div</div></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </section>
        <script>
           var section = document.getElementById("container");
    section.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target.className === "box") {
            alert("Worrking...");
        }
    }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when click on inner div Event occurs Because have class "box"

Or use this code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="container">
          <div class="box"><div>inner div</div></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </section>
        <script>
           var section = document.getElementById("container");
    section.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target.className === "box" || event.target.parentElement.className === "box") {
            alert("Worrking...");
        }
    }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```